# How can I access mutiple split arrays for plotting?

Tags: python, arrays, plot

So I started with a large chunk of data: many columns, thousands of rows, 100 separate measurements.  I put the data in one array, and I used split_array to split the one huge array into the 100 different measurements.  Now I need to plot all 100 measurements on the same plot.  My problem is I'm not sure how to access the split up arrays.  The split up arrays look something like this:

```
[array([[21.4284003, 0, 1, 4.0482, 92.2, 230.6, 0, 0, ' NaN '],
        [21.4364002, 0, 1, 3.9745, 91.8, 240.9, 0, 0, ' NaN '],
        ...
        [21.4704002, 0, 1, 3.8645, 91.8, 240.9, 0, 0, ' NaN ']], dtype=object),
 array([[22.4958395, 1, 1, 4.5837, 90.2, 285.9, 0, 0, ' NaN '], so on]
```

I am only interested in plotting the 1st and 4th columns of each array and I used some basic plotting code as follows.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
time = split_array[:,0]
conductance = split_array[:,3]
ax.line(time, conductance)
plt.show()
```

When I run this, I get the error message "list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple" with the error pointing to line 3.  My guess is that each array is being stored as a tuple and that split_array[:,0] is referring to the first array and not the first column in each array.  I have not been able to find much info on plotting split arrays so any help is appreciated.

Comment: The data is a list of arrays.  You can iterate over the list with a for loop and operate on individual arrays in the for loop suite.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you are trying to do but if your data is a list of arrays like this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
data = [np.array([[21.4284003, 0, 1, 4.0482, 92.2, 230.6, 0, 0, ' NaN '],
                  [21.4364002, 0, 1, 3.9745, 91.8, 240.9, 0, 0, ' NaN '],
                  [21.4704002, 0, 1, 3.8645, 91.8, 240.9, 0, 0, ' NaN ']], dtype=object),
        np.array([[22.4958395, 1, 1, 4.5837, 90.2, 285.9, 0, 0, ' NaN '],
                  [22.5958395, 1, 1, 4.7837, 90.2, 285.9, 0, 0, ' NaN '],
                  [22.6958395, 1, 1, 4.9837, 90.2, 285.9, 0, 0, ' NaN ']], dtype=object)
                  ]
```

You need to iterate over the list and plot each individual array in the suite:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
for a in data:
    time = a[:,0]
    conductance = a[:,3]
    ax.plot(time, conductance)
plt.show()
```